# Visiting multiple urls during a single test makes some requests appear as cancelled

Tags: cypress

I have following test case:

```
it('should visit two pages', function() {
  cy.visit('/entity-one/3378815/update');
  cy.url().should('include', '/entity-one/'); // also tried verifying all the data
  cy.visit('/entity-two');
  cy.url().should('include', '/entity-two');
});
```

The test above is passing however the test runner always show some of the xhr requests called while visiting the first url as cancelled. If I move the second visit statement into another test that immediately follows the test above then I don't see those requests as cancelled. I have tried to wait on those requests but that did not prevent them from turning to red (cancelled). I have also verified that the xhr requests do actually get completed as I can see the data returned by them and also by waiting on them however still somehow upon call to second visit their state flips to as cancelled.

Note: I have tried following to ensure the xhr requests are completed:

1. calling wait for a very long time
2. verifying data loaded on the first page which can only happen after the requests are completed
3. calling wait on the specific xhr requests by using intercepts

Why does cypress flips the state of completed xhr requests? and is this the expected behavior of cypress that we can call visit only once in a test?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `cypress\support\commands.js`

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
        return win.open(url, '_self'); 
      });
});
```

And use `cy.forceVisit("https://demo.yourURL")`

Comment: that also didn't work, thanks

Comment: @sttaq cypress does not support multiple URLs in the same test. If you want to use a different domain URL you need to create a separate test for it.

Comment: is it true for same domain urls as well? I am using same domain as shown in my example.